# Why is H always* the letter used to describe the level of a barrier?

Tags: options, barrier

A quick and (hopefully) easy question. Why?

*(always / often / when it's not *B*)

Comment: Is that for real?

Comment: @Kiwiakos as in is it a real question? Yes! i'm curious.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have any reference, but I think $H$ is for hitting.

Comment: Just did a little more digging - it looks like it's more likely related to the Heaviside function.

Comment: It's the "height of barrier" so H and B are natural choices for the variable. It is also the "level to be hit" so again H is natural.